# How to get audio samples into form where I can analyse it?

Tags: iphone, ios, objective-c, xcode, fft

I'm trying to develop a tone analyser for the iPhone using FFT(fast Fourier transform), but figur out how to get audio samples into a form where can analyze it. I just want an array with time and amplitude or something like that. Thanks in advance!